# Achieving ArcGIS Dissolve result with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, dissolve

I want to merge two or more adjacent lines (within a XY tolerance) to one line. The result from Dissolve in ArcGIS is what I aim for.

How can I do that in PostGIS?

See figure below.

[image]

Comment: Could you take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/262450/query-similar-linestrings-running-workouts-using-postgis ?

Comment: what makes the difference between getting one line and two?

Comment: @IanTurton, XY tolerance =100. Where the distance between lines is less then 100 = 1 line

Comment: And is it the average or a copy of one or the other?

Comment: @IanTurton, must be an average. I don't know how the ArcGIS Dissolve works.

Comment: Shame you can't check their source code

Comment: Can you share the data, for example as WKT strings?

Comment: https://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/use-postgis-topologies-to-clean-up-road-networks.html  you could try topology.  Otherwise this is a pretty complex workflow.